# Aspose.Words delete line(row) containing a Bookmark

Tags: aspose.words

I have a very basic helper method that sets Bookmark's text.

```
public static Bookmark SetBookmark(this Document doc, string bookmarkName, string value)
{
        var bm = doc.Range.Bookmarks[bookmarkName];
        if(bm == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException(string.Format("Bookmark {0} Not Found!", bookmarkName));
        bm.Text = value ?? string.Empty;
        return bm;
}
```

What I need is to remove a bookmark and **delete** line of text that contains it when a certain condition is met, e.g. when `value == null`. Any suggestions?

Sample document looks like:
 
Hello
 
[Bookmark]
 
Goodbye

Resulted document after removal:
 
Hello
 
Goodbye

Answer (score 0):

Please set the value of Bookmark.Text property to empty string to remove its content and use Bookmark.Remove method to remove the bookmark from the document. Bookmark.Remove method does not remove text inside the bookmark.

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: Bookmark.Remove deletes bookmark itself. What I need is to take out entire line in the document where that bookmark is/was located.

Comment: Please share the sample input and expected output documents via any free file sharer server e.g. Dropbox. I will then share the code example.  - I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: Unable to upload due to corporate policy, so presenting abstract sample here.

Comment: You can share test documents with test data to understand your requirements. I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the value of Bookmark.Text property to empty string to remove its content as shown in following code example. I already shared this in my previous answer.

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "Bookmark.doc");

// Use the indexer of the Bookmarks collection to obtain the desired bookmark.
Bookmark bookmark = doc.Range.Bookmarks["MyBookmark"];

// Remove the contents of bookmark.
bookmark.Text = "";

doc.Save(MyDir + @"Out.docx");
```

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.